# Get a count of consecutive dates

Tags: mysql, mariadb, group-by

I want to get a list of dates where there are consecutive dates and it's corresponding count.

For example, if the I have the following data set

```
Date
2021-07-28
2021-07-27
2021-07-26
2021-07-25
2021-07-24
2021-07-23
2021-07-22
2021-07-21
2021-07-18
2021-07-17
2021-07-14
2021-07-11
2021-07-09
2021-07-06
2021-07-04
2021-07-03
2021-07-02
```

The result I would like is where consecutive date count > x

```
2021-07-21  8
2021-07-17  2
2021-07-02  3
```

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem. If an explanation could be provided with the query that would be great, although not required.

Comment: [This SO answer from a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11541494/14952832) is pretty good, and it'll walk you through both the why and the how 

Comment: What is precise DB server version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As correctly noted by [Charlieface](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/220697/charlieface), this is a Gaps and Islands problem.  Another way of solving this specific variation – also involving a window function, though a different one this time – would go like this:

```
WITH
  partitioned AS
  (
    SELECT
      *
    , DATEDIFF(Date, '1970-01-01') - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date ASC) AS PartID
    FROM
      YourTable
  )
SELECT
  MIN(Date) AS StartDate
, COUNT(*)  AS DayCount
FROM
  partitioned
GROUP BY
  PartID
HAVING
  COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
  PartID
;
```

This solution relies on the fact that the difference between a representation of a date as an integer (`DATEDIFF(...)`) and the date's numerical position in an ordered sequence (`ROW_NUMBER() OVER ...`) is a constant value.  If we looked at the intermediate values returned by the functions in the `PartID` expression, we would find the following:

| Date | DATEDIFF(Date, '1970-01-01') | ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date ASC) | PartID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-02 | 18810 | 1 | 18809 |
| 2021-07-03 | 18811 | 2 | 18809 |
| 2021-07-04 | 18812 | 3 | 18809 |
| 2021-07-06 | 18814 | 4 | 18810 |
| 2021-07-09 | 18817 | 5 | 18812 |
| 2021-07-11 | 18819 | 6 | 18813 |
| 2021-07-14 | 18822 | 7 | 18815 |
| 2021-07-17 | 18825 | 8 | 18817 |
| 2021-07-18 | 18826 | 9 | 18817 |
| 2021-07-21 | 18829 | 10 | 18819 |
| 2021-07-22 | 18830 | 11 | 18819 |
| 2021-07-23 | 18831 | 12 | 18819 |
| 2021-07-24 | 18832 | 13 | 18819 |
| 2021-07-25 | 18833 | 14 | 18819 |
| 2021-07-26 | 18834 | 15 | 18819 |
| 2021-07-27 | 18835 | 16 | 18819 |
| 2021-07-28 | 18836 | 17 | 18819 |

As you can see, the difference between `DATEDIFF` and `ROW_NUMBER` (represented by the column `PartID`) is the same where dates are consecutive, and it is different for different sequences, which makes it a perfect candidate for a GROUP BY criterion.  And that is exactly what the query is using it for.  By the way, the date `1970-01-01` has no specific meaning in this case.  Any date could be used instead of it as long as it is a constant value.

Another important note to make – and it makes this answer substantially different from [Charlieface's suggestion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/297324) – is that all the dates must be unique for the method to work as expected.

A live demo of this solution can be found at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=f5ae0b2fb8df18a4b4589146ed481742&hide=3).

Comment: Hum, I always forget about the row-numbering method. But I get nervous about it because of the uniqueness requirement

Answer (score 2):

**This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem, of which there are a number of solutions.**

Here is one:

- We can identify the starting points of each island by using `LAG` to check the previous row (with a default for the first row)
- We can then number the islands using a running `COUNT`
- Then simply group by that number

```
WITH StartingPoints AS (
    SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN DATE_ADD(
          LAG(`Date`, 1, '1900-01-01') OVER (ORDER BY `Date`),
          INTERVAL 1 DAY
          ) < `Date` THEN 1 END AS IsStart
    FROM YourTable
),
Grouped AS (
    SELECT *,
        COUNT(IsStart) OVER (ORDER BY `Date` ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS GroupId
    FROM StartingPoints
)
SELECT
  MIN(`Date`) AS StartDate,
  COUNT(*) AS `Count`
FROM Grouped
GROUP BY GroupId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY GroupId DESC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=716ff2fcd983e6c4a2ffe887af94aa41)

Answer (score 0):

The solution which does not use user-defined variables and/or CTEs:

```sql
SELECT t1.`Date` range_start, 
       MIN(t2.`Date`) range_finish,
       DATEDIFF(MIN(t2.`Date`), t1.`Date`) + 1 range_length
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 ON t2.`Date` >= t1.`Date`
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM test t3
                   WHERE t3.`Date` = t1.`Date` - INTERVAL 1 DAY )
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM test t4
                   WHERE t4.`Date` = t2.`Date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY )
GROUP BY range_start
HAVING range_length > 1
ORDER BY range_start
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd87574aea9b024ebf1fe5096e31210f

`t1` is used for consecutive ranges starts selection (NOT EXISTS by `t3` ensures that there is no adjacent previous date).

Accordingly `t2` is used for consecutive ranges ends selection (NOT EXISTS by `t4` ensures that there is no adjacent next date).

Joining condition for each start filters all ends which are potentially the end of this particular range. Grouping and MIN() selects range end date which matches range start date from all candidates.

HAVING removes the ranges which' length is 1 day only.